# no aparece grub con gpt windows/ubuntu

Tags: grub2, windows, gpt

I have an asus k55VM. The problem is that after installing Windows 7, and then Ubuntu 12.10, grub does not appear.

Created the partition table with gparted, I did it in msdos format, but later installing windows 7 it did not accept it and said to do it in gpt format, therefore I deleted the disk (partition table?) and I create a partition with 160GB.

Later on I entered into the Live CD to ubuntu, where I created partitions for ubuntu... I installed and rebooted. Restarting grub does not appear, but the windows partitions do appear.

I hope someone can assist me with this. (I'm desperate)

Thank you in advance.

Solution?:

Thank you very much

hadDisk of 500gb the netbook es new

Comment: Please only use English on this site. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that Windows is installing in [EFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) mode whereas Ubuntu is installing in [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) mode. Switching between the two is awkward with most motherboards, so it's best to get your systems installed in the same mode.

Based on your description, your system is currently set up with the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), which Microsoft requires to boot the computer in EFI mode. As user73855 says, GPT is required for over-2TiB disks, but it's also the preferred partitioning system on EFI-based computers. Linux can boot in BIOS mode from a GPT disk, but Windows can't.

The easiest way to proceed may be to re-install Ubuntu, but make sure the installer boots in EFI mode, not in BIOS mode. Check your computer's manual or boot messages to learn how to get a boot menu when you start up. It may provide two CD/DVD boot options, one to boot in BIOS (aka legacy) mode and the other to boot in EFI (or UEFI) mode. If you can find such an option, select the EFI/UEFI mode boot. Re-installing Ubuntu in this way should do the trick.

If you can't find such a firmware option, your task becomes harder. You should be able to manage by manually installing an EFI boot loader for Linux. I've written [a Web page on this topic,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) so check it out to learn what's available and how to install one. Unfortunately, if you can't control the way your system boots an Ubuntu installer or other emergency Linux disc, you'll have to do the installation by renaming the Microsoft boot loader and installing your chosen boot loader using that name, at least temporarily.

An entirely different approach is to wipe everything on the disk and re-install both OSes in BIOS mode. This will require forcing the Windows installer to boot in that mode, though, which will be most easily accomplished if you can find a firmware option to control the installation medium's boot mode (BIOS vs. EFI). If you've got such an option, re-installing just Ubuntu in EFI mode will be easier than re-installing both OSes in BIOS mode.

A final option is to install my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) boot loader. Version 0.4.6 adds the ability to boot BIOS-mode OSes on firmwares that enable a switch. You'll need to change the `scanfor` option in the `refind.conf` file to include the `hdbios` option, though. You can install rEFInd from Windows (the documentation describes how) and make the change to `refind.conf`. When you're done, you should see a "generic" boot option appear for Ubuntu (it'll be labelled "boot from HD" or some such; I don't recall the exact wording). If you like, you can then make some additional changes to have rEFInd boot Linux more directly in any of several ways; see the "Options for Booting Linux" section of the rEFInd documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**Translation:** *Si puedes, copiate esto en lugar de tu pregunta*

I have an asus k55VM. The problem is that after installing Windows 7, and then Ubuntu 12.10, grub does not appear.

Created the partition table with gparted, I did it in msdos format, but later installing windows 7 it did not accept it and said to do it in gpt format, therefore I deleted the disk (partition table?) and I create a partition with 160GB.

Later on I entered into the Live CD to ubuntu, where I created partitions for ubuntu... I installed and rebooted. Restarting grub does not appear, but the windows partitions do appear.

I hope someone can assist me with this. (I'm desperate)

Thank you in advance.

**Solution?**:

**-ENGLISH**: well... I have no idea what is going on there, but GPT is for hard drives bigger than 2.2 TeraBytes. It would be good to know what HDD do you have (size at least). MBR is for most of the HDDs. Though GPT and MBR should not be your concern, unless if the laptop is new.

MSDOS format? I think that is for old partitions for old windows versions. NTFS is the used format for windows.
You can try to press SHIFT when booting up, that might bring grub up.
[Depending if you have more than 1 HDD, the grub will be installed into one of those. And if the wrong HDD gets booted first, then no wonder grub does not start. 
(what i mean: HDD1+HDD2, install grub on HDD2, reboot, HDD1 loads because of BIOS, grub does not start)]

This is how I would do it: 1: start/install windows7 where you create 2 partitions, 60 GB ntfs for windows, and the rest empty space. Reboot. 2: Install Ubuntu, create 3 partitions, one for "/" root, one for /home, and 4 GB for SWAP, (root must be primary, the rest does not matter), and the rest you can make a "shared" ntfs partition. And importantly, install grub on the HDD. You can see the options, but instead of installing it on a partition, install it directly on /sda.

Chill down, don't worry, if possible give us screenshots, or more info, so we can help you. Cheers.

**-ESPAÑOL**: bueno... no se que sucede, pero el GPT es para Discos Duros de mas de 2.2 TeraBytes. Seria bueno saber que tipo de DiscDur tienes (tamaño mas bien). MBR es para la mayoria de los DDs. Aunque no tendria que ver, a menos que sea nuevo el portatil.

Formato MSDOS? Creo que eso es para versiones antiguas de windows. Actualmente se usa el NTFS (ya sabrás).

Puedes intentar mantener pulsado el "Mayús" durante el arranque del pc, eso deberia sacar el GRUB.
[Dependiendo si tienes mas de un DD, grub será instalado en uno de los 2 (como lo habrás puesto) Y si lo pusiste al segundo DD, entonces normal que el grub no será iniciado. 
(lo que quiero decir: DD1+DD2, instalando grub en DD2, reiniciar, DD1 se inicia porque el BIOS lo tiene configurado asi, y no sucede nada, y claro es porque, el grub fue instalado en el DD2)]

Así lo haría yo: 1: iniciar/instalar windows 7 nadamás empezar. Ahi te creas 60GB para windows (lo instalas ahi), NTFS, y el resto espacio sin usar. Reinicias. 2: Instalas Ubuntu, creas 3 particiones, uno para "/", uno para "/home" y 4 GB para SWAP, ( "/" debe ser primario, el resto no importa), y el resto lo puedes hacer una particion NTFS para usarlo conjunto con windows y linux. Y lo mas importante, ahi en el instalador, seleccionar donde instalar el GRUB. Verás las opciones pero no lo instales en particiones, sino en el disco duro mismo ( "/sda"?)

Tranquilo, no te preocupes, si puedes danos capturas de pantalla, o más info para que podamos ayudarte. Suerte!

Comment: acabo de leer todas las respuestas: muchas gracias. windows need efi mode to install. The computer is new and has 500gb only.

Comment: acabo de leer todas las respuestas: muchas gracias. windows need efi mode to install. The computer is new and has 500gb only. The second response say that I have to reinstall ubuntu in efi mode. How can I install inthis way? My idea was to install in a partition of 90 gb etx4 ubuntu. Reading your answere, is obligatory the creation of 3 partition to install ubuntu? I made 4 gb swich partition also.